# How can I access to local variable from inner class method?

Tags: java

I cannot access `var` variable from inner class method. but java is accessing to class variable instead of local variable. How can I access to local variable instead of class variable from inner class method ?

```
class Foo {
    void test() {
        int var = 3;

        class Inner {
            int var = 1;

            void print_var_of_test() {
                System.out.println(var); // this line prints 1 why ?
                // I want this line to print var of test (3) function.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you give one of those variables a different name?

Comment: `print_var_of_test(int var)`

Comment: This isn't a case of a local variable and a class variable; it's an issue of two local variables.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, so you can edit my question to be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a local variable defined in a method of the outer class from an inner class if the inner class defines already a variable with the same name.
You could use distinct names to distinguish them.

As workaround to keep the same variable names, you could change the signature of `print_var_of_test()` to accept an `int`.
In this way, outside the inner class you could pass the `int var` variable as the method is invoked.

```
class Foo {

  void test() {
    int var = 3;

    class Inner {
        int var = 1;

        void print_var_of_test(int var) {
          System.out.println("outer var=" + var);
          System.out.println("inner var=" + this.var);
        }
    }

    Inner inner = new Inner();
    inner.print_var_of_test(var);
  }

}
```

Comment: is there a any other solution to solving this name problem ? because using different names is nonsense for me.

Comment: No you cannot. But as suggested by @mre you can use a workaround as changing the method to accept a parameter. I updated

Comment: Can you please justify why you cannot access? Last but not least this is not an inner class, but a local nested class.

Answer (score 1):

You do that by picking another name for either the local variable or the inner class variable.

Since the inner class and the method variable are defined in the same source method, you should always be able to change one of them. There is never a situation in which you don't have the permission/right/capability to change one but not the other.

Comment: can I solve this problem without using different names ? using different names (this way) doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @Nomad there isn't. The authors of the Java Language didn't think it was nonsense.

Comment: What  kind of answer is this? I can also do not use local nested classes, then what? Of course I can rename it, but this does not provide an answer to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

What about naming inner class var as varInner if you want to compare between it and the original one?